# dynamically altering an inline in win8

Tags: string, xaml, windows-8, formatting

I want to make a sort of typing game; as the user types the textbox/textblock/contentcontrol should highlight(turn into bold) the specific word that the user is supposed to be typing. From what I've researched, I can't grasp the concept behind Dependency properties (to make Inlines work), but I pretty much have the logic nailed down, I would just like to know how to 'highlight' that word (from the C# side)